# adding an assign function as property to an object in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, function, variables

for the sake of fun and exploring nodeJS I made an object

```
var f15c = {
fuel : 10000,
IRST: true,
AESA: true,
speed: 2500,
Ammo:
 {
    AMRAAM: 6,
    Python5: 2,
    Delilah: 3,
 },
tailnumber : the question begins here.
}
```

The problem came when I wanted to add tailnumber that is not the same for every plane but should be assigned to the plane.
what is the methode?

```
var f15c = {
...
tailnumber = function (tn){"whats should i add here?"}
}
```

or

```
var f15c = {
...
tailnumber: ?? what should i place here?
SetTailNumber = function(tn)
 {
   tailnumber=tn;
 }
}
```

or must I have the entire F15c as a function?

```
var f15c = function(tn) {
...
tailnumber = tn;
```

but then i cannot set the entire variables complex.

or perhaps I'm doing it wrong and should refer the variable as an individual F15 and use a different function to create it?
but then how do I make that field in a way it is unassigned and waiting to be assigned (and then saves the assigned number)?

would appreciate some heads up

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It is much more important question than the "how to use function". To what you are doing - it looks like that define class and pass tailnumber into the constructor is much better option.

Comment: You should accept Jelmer's response below as it is complete and elegant. Just remember the concept of using `this`: it represents the calling object.

Answer (score 2):

The secret is to use `this` to refer to a property of the own object

`var f15c = {
...
tailnumber: null,
setTailNumber : function(tn)
 {
   this.tailnumber=tn;
 }
}`

Then:

`f15c.setTailNumber(1234);
   console.log(f15c.tailnumber);`

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean you want to set a value to a property?

```js
var f15c = {
  _tailnumber: 0,
  set tailnumber(newtailnumber) {
    this._tailnumber = newtailnumber;
  },

  get tailnumber() {
    return this._tailnumber
  }
};

f15c.tailnumber = "304";
console.log(f15c.tailnumber);
console.log(f15c);
```

Comment: Bonus for using `set` and `get`.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Comment: Still the full solution should contain a class: f15c isa plain (i guess), and an instance of f15c has a certain tail number.

Comment: Correct. If the object is reused one might think only the new set is applied, while all references are affected. But then we dive deep :-)

Comment: what does this helps you
       get tailnumber() {
        return this._tailnumber
       }

rather than calling the f15c.tailnumber?

also,
i run the code snippet and not sure why did it return in the

     console.log(f15c);

this reply
     {
        "_tailnumber": "304",
       "tailnumber": "304"
     }
?

in my case i recieve
    console.log(f15c);

    console.log(f15c.tailnumber);
console:

    Object {fuel: 10000, IRST: true, AESA: true, speed: 2500, Ammo: 
    Object, …}

    123

Comment: Well, in my example I did not copy all the other properties to your object. Because the only one relevant to your question was the tailnumber. Just focus on that. For diagnosis, you could put the tailnumber get/set and _tailnumber first in the object, so you can actually see it in the console...

Comment: yea i figured it would hide in the ...

but you simply wrote { content } and i wasn't sure why does it appear as  Object { content }.

I undestood its simply cause you trimmed it

Comment: _what does this helps you get tailnumber() { return this._tailnumber } rather than calling the f15c.tailnumber?_

I use a different property (`_tailnumber`) to store some internal value. Then, I define a get/set property (`tailnumber`) that will be used outside. Every time some code tries to set the property `tailnumber`, the set function will be called. Every time some code tries to get the property `tailnumber`, the get function will be called. 

See https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/set

Comment: The thing "Object" was added because your console logger does that, and the one used at stack overflow does not...

Comment: oh ok so you already dived to the private/public vars.
this part i allready know about.
yet I don't know where should I insert the declaration 'private' in the var or func JS.

simply 'private tailnumber : null '?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161639/discussion-between-jelmer-jellema-and-user2956754).

Comment: *what does this helps you get tailnumber() { return this._tailnumber } rather than calling the f15c.tailnumber?* ---- by using `set` and `get` on the same property name, you have a real set/get behavior: `f15c.tailnumber(1)` sets the number and `f15c.tailnumber` gets it for you. Then you have to store the actual value for tailnumber somewhere else. Using _tailnumber is nice because it keeps the name for simplicity.